# Looping through wordpress and adding a share button to buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have been trying to loop through a wordless plugin that displays posts as properties and have gotten it right. The problem is that I want a link on every line that allows me to share status updates with Buddy press.

The problem is that when I press the button to share it always posts the first post ID no matter what.

Please can you assist me?

```
<div class="ich-settings-main-wrap">
<div id="user-profile">
    <div class="table-responsive property-list">
        <table class="table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?php _e( 'Images', 'wcp-rem' ); ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Property', 'wcp-rem' ); ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Share', 'wcp-rem' ); ?></th>
                <th class="hidden-xs"><?php _e( 'Type', 'wcp-rem' ); ?></th>
                <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><?php _e( 'Added', 'wcp-rem' ); ?></th>
                <th class="hidden-xs"><?php _e( 'Purpose', 'wcp-rem' ); ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Status', 'wcp-rem' ); ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Edit', 'wcp-rem' ); ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Delete', 'wcp-rem' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php 
                $current_user_data = wp_get_current_user();
                $args = array(
                    'author'    => $current_user_data->ID,
                    'post_type' => 'rem_property',
                    'post_status' => array( 'pending', 'draft', 'future', 'publish' )
                );
                $myproperties = new WP_Query( $args );
                if( $myproperties->have_posts() ){
                    while( $myproperties->have_posts() ){ 
                        $myproperties->the_post(); ?>   
                            <tr>
                                <td class="img-wrap">
                                    <?php do_action( 'rem_property_picture', get_the_id(), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                                </td>
                                <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'rem_property_address', true); ?></td>
                                <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Share</a></td>
                                <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo ucfirst(get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'rem_property_type', true )); ?></td>
                                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><?php the_time('Y/m/d'); ?></td>
                                <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo ucfirst(get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'rem_property_purpose', true )); ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php
                                        $p_status = get_post_status(get_the_id());
                                        $status_class = ($p_status == 'publish') ? 'label-success' : 'label-info' ;
                                        $a = $row['get_the_id()'];
                                        echo $a;
                                    ?>
                                    <span class="label <?php echo $status_class; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($p_status); ?></span></td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php edit_post_link( '<span class="dashicons dashicons-edit"></span>'); ?></td>
                                <td>    
                                    <?php $delete_url = get_delete_post_link(get_the_id());
                                        if ($delete_url != '') { ?>
                                            <a href="<?php echo $delete_url; ?>"><span class="dashicons dashicons-trash"></span></a>
                                        <?php }
                                    ?>
                                </td>






                                <td><form method="POST" action='' class="button" >
                                    <input type="SUBMIT" name='button1'>
                                    </form>

                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
            <?php 
                    }
                }
            ?>

          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<?php if (isset($_POST['button1'])) 
                                         {  global $bp, $user_id, $myproperty;
                                           $post_id = $a; // replace your post id
                                             $user_id = $bp->loggedin_user->id;

                                            $post = $a;
                                            $title = $post->post_title;
                                            $content = $post->post_excerpt;
                                            $user_fullname = bp_core_get_user_displayname($user_id);

                                            bp_activity_add(array(
                                            'action' => '<a href="'.site_url().'/members/'.bp_get_loggedin_user_username().'">'.$user_fullname.'</a> updated below post',
                                            'content' => get_permalink($post_id),
                                            'component' => 'blog_post',
                                            'type' => 'update_post',
                                            'primary_link' => get_permalink($post_id),
                                            'user_id' => $user_id

                                            ));}
                                                ?>
```

Comment: Where are you telling the button *which* post to share?

Comment: with variable $a? but for some reason it doesn't work. What would you say would be the best way to get the id from the row so that it can work?

Comment: You need to set up your form corectly - at the moment you are doing no form processing at all. Your form is empty except for the button, so you're not submitting any values. You are also not trying to access the posted values from the $_POST after the form is submitted. Have a look for some tutorials on how to use HTML & PHP to submit data in a form.